# Tk Python - .trace leaves reference to object and doesnt allow the object to be garbage collected

Tags: python, tkinter, trace

the basics of my problem is this, I have an object which gets created and destroyed fine (i.e. garbage collected) until I introduce the below line:

```
self.variableA.trace("w", self.printSomeStuff)
```

variableA is a stringVar and is set up as shown below

```
self.variableA = tk.StringVar(self.detailViewHolderFrame)
self.variableA.set(self.OPTIONS0[0])
```

for some reason this line causes there to be a reference to the object and hence it never gets garbage collected and I end up with a memory leak.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might get round this other than using a different widget.

I can expand on the code further but first I wanted to see if this is a common issue and if anybody know the underlying problem.

Comment: object.destroy() maybe?

Comment: I believe you would need to provide more code.

Comment: I agree Anand S Kumar, I was hinting at something that might be helpful, not attempting to offer a full answer. :)

Comment: are you explicitly destroying the object, or just expecting it to get destroyed when it goes out of scope? Have you tried explicitly destroying the object? Have you tried explicitly removing the trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to delete the callback(s) using `trace_vdelete()`. Hopefully that will remove the reference(s) to the tk variable.

```
def cb(*args):
    print args

v = StringVar()
v.trace('r', cb)
v.trace('w', cb)
v.set(10)   # cb called
# ('PY_VAR5', '', 'w')
v.get()     # cb called
# ('PY_VAR5', '', 'r')
# '10'
print v.trace_vinfo()
# [('w', '139762300731216cb'), ('r', '139762505534512cb')]
for ti in v.trace_vinfo():
    print "Deleting", ti
    v.trace_vdelete(*ti)
# Deleting ('w', '139762300731216cb')
# Deleting ('r', '139762505534512cb')
print v.trace_vinfo()
#
```

You will need to figure out how to call `trace_vdelete()`, possibly you can do that from the `__del__()` method of the tk variable by subclassing and overriding `__del__()`:

```
class MyStringVar(StringVar):
    def __del__(self):
        for t in self.trace_vinfo():
            self.trace_vdelete(*t)
        StringVar.__del__(self)
```

## **Update**

As [Blckknght pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344725/tk-python-trace-leaves-reference-to-object-and-doesnt-allow-the-object-to-be#comment52567334_32344990), `__del__` will not be called until just before the object is garbage collected, and this will not happen when the `StringVar` is being traced because an additional reference is held.

One solution is to use an external function as the trace callback.

If, however, you want the trace callback to be a method of your class, a solution is to set your class up as a context manager, i.e. a class that can be used in a `with` statement. Then a cleanup method can be called when the with statement terminates. The cleanup method will delete the trace callbacks and this will remove the reference to your object from the tk trace system. It should then be available for garbage collection. Here's an example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class YourClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = tk.StringVar()
        self.s.trace('w',self.cb)
        self.s.trace('r',self.cb)

    def __enter__(self):
        """Make this class usable in a with statement"""
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        """Make this class usable in a with statement"""
        self.cleanup()

    def __del__(self):
        print 'YourClass.__del__():'

    def cb(self, *args):
        print 'YourClass.cb(): {}'.format(args)

    def cleanup(self):
        print 'YourClass.cleanup():'
        for t in self.s.trace_vinfo():
            print 'YourClass.cleanup(): deleting {}'.format(t)
            self.s.trace_vdelete(*t)
```

**Demo**

```
>>> obj = YourClass()
>>> obj.s.set('hi')
YourClass.cb(): ('PY_VAR5', '', 'w')
>>> obj.s.get()
YourClass.cb(): ('PY_VAR5', '', 'r')
'hi'
>>> obj.s.trace_vinfo()
[('r', '139833534048848cb'), ('w', '139833534047728cb')]
>>> del obj
>>>
```

N.B. `YourClass.__del__()` was *not* called because the trace system still holds a reference to this instance of `YourClass`. You could manually call the `cleanup()` method:

```
>>> obj = YourClass()
>>> obj.cleanup()
YourClass.cleanup():
YourClass.cleanup(): deleting ('r', '139833533984192cb')
YourClass.cleanup(): deleting ('w', '139833533983552cb')
>>> del obj
YourClass.__del__():
```

Calling `cleanup()` removes the references to the `YourClass` instance and garbage collection can occur. It's easy to forget to call `cleanup()` every time, and it's a pain too. Using the context manager makes calling clean up code easy:

```
>>> with YourClass() as obj:
...     obj.s.set('hi')
...     obj.s.get()
...     obj.s.trace_vinfo()
... 
YourClass.cb(): ('PY_VAR2', '', 'w')
YourClass.cb(): ('PY_VAR2', '', 'r')
'hi'
[('r', '139833534001392cb'), ('w', '139833533984112cb')]
YourClass.cleanup():
YourClass.cleanup(): deleting ('r', '139833534001392cb')
YourClass.cleanup(): deleting ('w', '139833533984112cb')
```

Here `__exit__()` was called automatically upon exit from the `with` statement and it delegates to `cleanup()`. Deleting or rebinding `obj` will cause garbage collection, as will the variable going out of scope for example upon return from a function:

```
>>> obj = None
YourClass.__del__():
```

One final benefit of using the context manager is that `__exit()__` will always be called upon exit from the context manager, for whatever reason. This includes any unhandled exceptions, so your clean up code will always be called:

```
>>> with YourClass() as obj:
...     1/0
... 
YourClass.cleanup():
YourClass.cleanup(): deleting ('r', '139833395464704cb')
YourClass.cleanup(): deleting ('w', '139833668711040cb')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
>>> del obj
YourClass.__del__():
```

Comment: I don't think `__del__` will work as a place to call `trace_vdelete` from. That's because it will only be called when there are no references to the object, which because the trace system holds a reference will never be the case. You also can't do it in for the containing object in the questioner's code because a reference to `self` will be held as part of the bound method `self.printSomeStuff`.

Comment: @Blckknght : thanks for that. I wasn't sure that it would work with `__del__` , but I've tested it and you're right: `__del__` is not called when the `StringVar` is being traced, but it is called when it's not being traced. Deleting the trace callbacks with `trace_vdelete()` does make the object available for collection - as `__del__` will again be called when the host object is collected.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks for the extensive answer, I learnt a great deal. @mhawke I used your code above and it did kind of work, the only issue was it entered the "enter"" method quickly followed by the "exit" method, which means it deleted the "stringVar" before the widget could use it. But due to learning how to delete the trace on the stringVar I was able to call the cleanUp" method externally on the instance before disposing of it. Not the cleanest solution but it works. If anyone can think of why the instance would run the "enter" followed by "exit" method I'm all ears.

Comment: @TomL: yes, the downside of using a context manager with a `with` statement as above is that you need to perform all activity on the object within the body of the `with`.